# SRC folder is not created in Jasmine framework

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

`src` folder not created even after running "`npx jasmine init`" in vscode terminal.

This is the folder directory is created but I need to add "`ts`" and "`spec.ts`" in
`src` directory but **couldn't find one**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na4jT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by creating `src` folder in workspace manually:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.imgur.com/vgv8JAY .jpg

And in jasmine.json, replace `"spec_dir": "spec"` with
`"spec_dir": "src"`.